# Date in Email Scheduling in Bi publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

I want to Scheduled a File in BI publisher using Email option..

I want the attachment and Mail Subject and Mail Body to have sysdate ..

I tried with %d, %m,%y it works for FTP destination but for Email it is not working . please help me

i want the Report 'Sample' to be scheduled via mail like 'Sample_11022016', is it possible in BIP

Answer (score 0):

I don't think BIP provides a way of changing the filename when the output is sent over e-mail. That option is provided for FTP to prevent older files from getting overwritten at destination.

The best one can do is to print the report extracted date somewhere in the output file. Like in the top corner or as a header/footer on every page. When the e-mail is delivered to the recipient, the mail client will show the date and time it was received.